# Approx(): Need at least two non-NA values to interpolate R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `nnetar` for some time series forecasting, and running into an issue when the data has repeating values (i.e. the same counts observed in a time period). To reproduce the error I have created a list of values and replaced the first 10 values with a 0:

```
dummy.ls <- runif(n=80)

for(i in 1:10)
  dummy.ls[i] <- 0

fit <- nnetar(dummy.ls, lambda=0)
```

When running the `nnetar` function I receive the following error:

```
Error in approx(idx, x[idx], tt, rule = 2) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I see similar errors in other questions, but unsure how to avoid the error?

Comment: Add [noise](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/jitter.html) maybe?

Comment: I do need the counts to remain above 0. But this did make me rethink the lambda parameter. Setting to 'auto' seems to keep forecasts above 0 using the automated selection

Comment: you can use the `jitter` function as Sotos recommended while keep all changes on the positive side. For instance, if `vec <- rep(0, 10)`, while `jitter(vec)` does ("can", it's random after all) produce negatives, `vec + abs(vec - jitter(vec))` are all non-negative.

Comment: In addition, for forecasting, I would reccoment you use `forecast` package created by Rob Hydman and presented in [this book](https://otexts.com/fpp2/)